# Error while running my run.sh (linux)

Tags: linux, error-handling, sh, vps

I recently encountered this error while running my run.sh. I am trying to run a Runescape Private Server on my linux VPS; this is a large error. Please assist me, I dont know what other details to add.

Error:

```
jacob@ace:~/Server/source$ sh run.sh
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-server       to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server,
              because you are running on a server-class machine.


-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
run.sh: 1: run.sh: deps/poi.jar: Permission denied
run.sh: 1: run.sh: deps/mysql.jar: Permission denied
run.sh: 1: run.sh: deps/mina.jar: Permission denied
```

run.sh:

```
java -Xmx800m -cp bin;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar; server.Server
read
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `#!/bin/sh -vx` as the first line of your `run.sh` script (to get a trace of he shell).

You probably need to quote the classpath, i.e.

```
   java -Xmx800m -cp 'bin;deps/poi.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar;deps/jython.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar;' server.Server
   read
```

I strongly suggest to take a few hours to read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Answer (score 0):

You must change `;` to `:` of that i'm 100% sure!
Maybe that will fix your errors.

revision 718 RSPS runner(maybe useful for others searching this):

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -cp bin:lib/*: com.rs.Launcher true true false
```